# Separate pieces of Javascript in the same file

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have the following code inside a file called additional.js for a WordPress website I'm working on:

```
// Fade in for news posts

jQuery(".elementor-post").each(function(i) {
    jQuery(this).delay(250 * i).fadeIn(1000);
});





// Alphabetical Filter for Products

var $boxes = $('.elementor-posts-container > .elementor-post');

var $btns = $('.alphabet-btn').click(function() {
  var id = this.id;
  if (id == 'all') {
    $boxes.show()
  } else {
    $boxes.hide().filter(function() {
      var re = new RegExp('^' + id, 'i');
      return re.test($(this).text().trim());
    }).show()
  }
  $btns.removeClass('alphabet-active');
  $(this).addClass('alphabet-active');
})
```

The first part is a simple timed fade in for my blog posts and the second part is the js for an alphabetical filter on my products page.

Currently, the alphabetical filter is acting strangely. If you go here and click on B, for example, http://staging.morningsidepharm.com/products/generic-medicines/ if filters and leave the product beginning with B but then it fades in all of the other products after this - This is only on the initial click... after that, when you click around it seems to be acting as it should.

If I remove the first bit of code from the top of my file:

```
jQuery(".elementor-post").each(function(i) {
    jQuery(this).delay(250 * i).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Everything in the alphabet search works correctly, even on the initial click.

Which makes me believe there is something conflicting in the two bits of code.

Do I need to END the first bit of code somehow? or I there something else conflicting here?

I tried separating them and putting them in different .js files, but I guess that doesn't work because they both are still fired when the page loads.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm so close! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first part you use a syntax of `JQuery()` and in the second you use another `$()` test by changing `JQuery()` by `$()` in the first part of your code, maybe that makes conflict.

Comment: Thanks, Kike, Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work... I think I have to use jQuery instead of $ because it's Wordpress. However, I have tried both ways for both areas of code and neither work properly... Do you know of a way I can find out whats happening? Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue.

In the first bit of code, I'm targeting the .elementor-post selector without being specific to which .elementor-post I want to target. This meant it would affect the div .elementor-post sitewide.

Adding a container class and changing the top part of the code to the following fixed things:

```
// Fade in for news posts

jQuery(".fade-in-post-container .elementor-post").each(function(i) {
    jQuery(this).delay(250 * i).fadeIn(1000);
});
```